# Tips for golfing in Nim

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/)? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to Nim (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Answer (score 9):

## Use the `future` module

The `future` module contains two main byte-saving features: lambdas and list comprehensions. Lambdas are extremely useful.

For example, this:

```
proc f(s:any):any=s&", world!"
```

can be shortened to this:

```
import future
s=>s&", world!"
```

which saves a byte. Note, however, that lambdas can't be used outside of a parameter list -- so to test your code, you'll have to do something like this:

```
import future
proc test(f: string -> string) = echo f "Hello"
test(s=>s&", world!")
```

As well, list comprehensions can be used with the `future` module. For example, this code prints a seq (`@[...]`) of all squares less than 100 divisible by 4:

```
import future
echo lc[x*x|(x<-1..9,x*x mod 4==0),int]
```

Comment: For a fairer comparison it should be noted that you can sometimes use `any` instead of `string` (I'm assuming you chose the longest type name), but this still saves regardless.

Comment: @Sp3000 I didn't know you could use `any`, thanks for the tip! You should post that as an answer.

Comment: For an even better comparison, you can do `proc(s:any):any=s&", world!"`, dropping the `<space>f` for an anonymous `proc`

Comment: The name has been changed to sugar, and future has been deprecated.

Comment: I think this change was approx around the 1.x boundary.

Answer (score 9):

### Unsigned operators

When working with nonnegative integers, sometimes it's better to use unsigned operators. Specifically, if possible, use `/%` and `%%` instead of `div` and `mod`.

Answer (score 9):

### Flexible call syntax

Nim is pretty flexible when it comes to function call syntax. For example, here are some ways to call a function with one argument:

```
ord(c)
ord c
c.ord
```

And ways to call a function with two arguments:

```
max(a,b)
a.max(b)
a.max b
```

Choose the golfiest version that works right for your situation, especially regarding precedence. For example, compare:

```
abs(n)+2
n.abs+2
(abs n)+2
```

As opposed to:

```
abs(n+2)
(n+2).abs
abs n+2
```

Comment: Note that `max a,b` even works (sometimes).

Comment: You can also drop the space when followed by a `"` (quotation mark): `len"Hello world!"`

Answer (score 4):

## Use `on` and `off` as a boolean value

`on` / `off` are aliases for true / false.

Answer (score 3):

## Use `;` to end statements

Oftentimes, a lot of Nim bytes come from the mandatory indentation of two spaces. This can sometimes be avoided by utilizing `;` to break statements.
For example (a bit contrived, but nevertheless effectively demonstrating the idea):

```
while 1>0:echo "Hello";echo"World"
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1>0 for true and 0>1 for false

In Nim, there is no implicit conversion of int->bool or bool->int. It is thus advantageous for golfing to use `1>0` or `0>1` to get the values for true and false, as one might use `1`/`0` in C. This can help with, for example, the creation of infinite loops.