# Repeat Values In Array

Tags: code-golf, array

Given two arrays of non-negative integers \$A = [A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n]\$ and \$R = [R_1,R_2,\ldots,R_n]\$ which are equal in length, return an array which has the element \$A_1\$ repeated \$R_1\$ times, then element \$A_2\$ repeated \$R_2\$ times, all the way up to \$A_n\$.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden. As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program wins.

#### Test Cases

| \$A\$ | \$R\$ | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,3]` | `[1,2,2,3,3,3]` |
| `[6,0,0,6]` | `[5,1,1,0]` | `[6,6,6,6,6,0,0]` |
| `[100,100]` | `[0,0]` | `[]` |

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139824/66833)

Comment: Pretty sure this is run-length decoding, just with the runs and the lengths separated.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/i/@Hl@o@a1hyd9HDnDCAd@f9/dHS0oY6RjnGsDpQGMqLNdAyA0AzINNUxBEIDsKihgYEOEAOZBiCRWAA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 27 bytes

```hs
(concat.).zipWith replicate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDsIwDEV3TuGBASS3SkB0okdgZggZ3CilEWmwmkyIsxNMhb6s//QG/4nyw8dYx/5Wd@6ZHJV2374CX0OZYPEcgyhfi88lQw/GGI0HPFr8t4DpUEk6wRNqiVqtVgrlBNXP2M1MIcmLmfgCvIRUYAtmBILhbQYke27WFQv148ZI91wbx/wF)

These built-ins have long names, but I haven't found anything shorter.

Answer (score 8):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 12 bytes

```
(*Zxx*).flat
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfQyuqokJLUy8tJ7Hkv7VCcWKlQppGjUq8pkJafpGCho2hgpGCsZ2OApShqQMUM1MwAEIzkKipgiEQGkDEDQ0MFIAYJG4AEvsPAA)

- `xx` is Raku's replication operator.  It produces a list of a number of copies of its left argument given by its right argument.  (Very conveniently, though irrelevant for this problem, the left-hand side is re-evaluated the requested number of times, so for example `rand xx 10` will produce a list of ten different random numbers.)
- `Z` is the zip "meta-operator."  It can be prepended to any other operator to produce a new operator that zips two lists together using the original operator.
- The asterisks make this a "WhateverCode" expression, a short way of defining anonymous functions.  The first and second argument to the function will take the place of the first and second asterisk, respectively.
- `.flat` flattens the list of replicated lists.

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 1 byte

```
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqCjYKBgBcS6egrOQT5u/5X/a3KlJmfkKxgqGCkYKwBBmgKEDRE2BXIMgepBwmZA2kDBDCIBYirA1BsYgDBEwlLBQsEc2aD/AA)

Simple built-in solution: The [copy](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d400.htm) verb.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 3 bytes

```r
rep
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/KLXgf5qGoZWxDhBrcqVpJGuY6RgAoZmmTrKGqY4hEBpoQiQMDQx0gBgkYQAS/A8A)

In [R](https://www.r-project.org/) many functions are vectorized and so is `rep` - it happens to work correctly for this challenge.

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s><sub>44</sub></s> 43 bytes

−1 thanks to Arnauld.

```javascript
A=>R=>A.flatMap((a,i)=>Array(R[i]).fill(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@9/R1i7I1s5RLy0nscQ3sUBDI1EnUxMoUFSUWKkRFJ0Zq6mXlpmTo5Goqfk/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jTSPaUMdIxzhWE87Q5EJTYKZjAIRmICWmOoZAaIBFkaGBgQ4QgxQZgBX8BwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```python
lambda*a:sum(map(lambda x,*y:x*y,*a),())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBCsMgFATQvadwqTILbWgWQk5iXfxSpIFqJE1BT29/SRmGgbeY2o/nVqaRltt4Ub4/yJB/f7LKVNUJssF030yHIQ2l9aAlhOBwwRTx3wgRwgzLmRmvcBx7srMWXGb7oyhE2nZ@7XItknzd13KopDoaf38B)

-1 thanks to Jonathan Allan!

-1 thanks to loopy walt!

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##LczBCsMgEATQu1/hUWUPa0NzEPIlWw9bijRQjaQJxK@3G1KGYeAdprbtvZShp@nRP5yfL3Ycvns2mau5QB/QAh3RNXBsgaLtPBGRhxsMEf4bQRGNgJJR8A5eghd7RJAK40lRqbSs562ei@ZQ17lsJhkBa/sP)

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcxBCsMgFATQvadwqTILbWgWQk5iXfxSpIFqJE1BT29/SRmGgbeY2o/nVqaRltt4Ub4/yJB/f7LKVNUJssF030yHIQ2l9aAlhOBwwRTx3wgRwgzLmRmvcBx7srMWXGb7oyhE2nZ@7XItknzd13KopDoaf38B) swapping arguments and outputting tuples.

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/),  <sup><s>27</s></sup>  25 bytes

```factor
[ [ <array> ] 2map-flat ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY29CsIwFIX3PsV5AUsa0UFF3MTFRZxKh0tIIZi24eY6lNJnjzGCw/nh48DpycjE6fm43a8HEDPNES/Lo/Uw0xCct1y/xXknzkYEtiJzYDcKjlW1oIHGFiuAf890l3sDlfmCfU6V/ctVYfitlSpaU4sWp3J9Rgc9UNj0ngRd0sLugjrCeEucPg)

Takes input as `R A`.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1 byte

```apl
/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X/9/2qO2CY96@x51NT/qXfOod8uh9caP2iY@6psaHOQMJEM8PIP/GyoYKRgrpCmAaS5TIG2oYADkmwFJAwUzLgMwz9DAAIQB)

Comment: [Works in BQN too.](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkC8K4p+oMeKAvzLigL8zIEYgMeKAvzLigL8zCjXigL8x4oC/MeKAvzAgRiA24oC/MOKAvzDigL82CjDigL8wIEYgMTAw4oC/MTAw4p+p)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
r9C
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=r9C&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0A%5B5%2C1%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B6%2C0%2C0%2C6%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%5B100%2C100%5D&debug=0)

Takes input as `R,A`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 39 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[0,*b]*1**b[:1]@[(),*zip(a)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Lc5RCsIwDAbg952ib7YlQqs4ZDDwHrUPKVIc2K6UDpzgSXwZiN7J25ixEcIPXwLJ65vGcu3j9Pbt-TMUvz3-NjcM7oIMwTVGgXRWaimdabQ9GS5APrrEUdh1_YmtMUbDDvYW1rRQGVODoqoJD6Cp1MJaKaAmVjPZyuc-sDiENLIupD4XhjnjWPk-szsQRhaQLs4IKJqUu1i45zQTYnlimpb8Aw)

Of course, there is also the `repeat` builtin.

#### How?

Beside the usual bending over backwards to avoid the explicit numpy import this uses the fact that if we write \$c_i = [b_i]\$ then, formally, \$c_1 a_1 + c_2 a_2 + ... + c_n a_n\$ is a dot product. It is mildly tricky to set up an array of equal length sequences because numpy will just create an additional dimension and create an array of scalars. Here we prepend a different length sequence, forcing a ragged array (after using zip to create a list of singleton tuples). To match we must also prepend one value to the length array. The 1**b[:1] factor, mathematically a nop, is there to trigger a coercion cascade to numpy arrays-

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
¨£ẋf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBUCIsIiIsIsKowqPhuotmIiwiIiwiWzEsMiwzXSxbMSwyLDNdXG5bNiwwLDAsNl0sWzUsMSwxLDBdXG5bMTAwLDEwMF0sWzAsMF0iXQ==)

This two-byte solution should work, but it seems to bork when the length is an array only of zeros: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBUCIsIiIsIsO44biKIiwiIiwiWzEsMiwzXSxbMSwyLDNdXG5bNSwxLDEsMF0sWzYsMCwwLDZdXG5bMCwwXSxbMTAwLDEwMF0iXQ==)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
Y"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P1Lp//9oMx0DIDSL5Yo21TEEQoNYAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D9S6b@6rq56hEvI/2hDHSMd41guOG2mYwCEZkCWqY4hEBqA5AwMdIAYyALKxQIA).

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 7 bytes

```matlab
repelem
```

It seem's that TIO's version of Octave doesn't have this built-in.

Comment: @LuisMendo The Octave version on my computer (7.2.0) has both [`repelem`](https://docs.octave.org/v7.2.0/Special-Utility-Matrices.html#index-repelem) and [`repelems`](https://docs.octave.org/v7.2.0/Special-Utility-Matrices.html#index-repelems), and their usage are different.

Comment: Ah, so they finally introduced it. Nice

Answer (score 4):

## [Goruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby/9289?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C19.2033#9289), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b)

```ruby
->a,b{a.fl{[_1]*b.sh}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVbdbts2FL73U5w6aSy5imKvazEE9dIfpNtuVqAFdjHDEyiJttlSlEBSaWxJfZHd9GJ7hb3L9jQ7JCX5p2nRYTFi0uef53znkL__Ict48_GfQXkCP-RmD4WkvEwpnMMg4UQpeBW_pYkeADx9usr5MloTtYYZVM0AaTdUxrmiAZz-cv36-as318jptgEIxlEmpUvIqF7naZQxpZhYQRbAmARwFiMbQKPSnvE5zJGvKF-GNoIFLKCuZ5ARnaxRO3LGlJf588nCWmBLNHJ2Bs4eQBQpKtIo8rRx5ENVj4lcqbplA8RhzESKxkJ6Q7g3LGSeVLUNwbpJiSY1nH7AyA6J0Az9MCGce6cffOP39MOeUcuwrvyW2tiVckVbgoaro_BMHny4BFUWVDpxkQ66773EtskedDk9zodCmdEogAxXEwmJOe2YLh6JnIvfTioV6jxS4UqVsXcRXvjV0AvHV_4QHsBruqK3RUhVQgrqnZ75TXNhdbNwJWnhST9UudQRQiXNoWZdTpkzaYMyQqiuS0kNpfDOLhXbUh-ePAF2dML2MK7cuVC6B0nyGXAkwVdgIwnAWiNCqx4mGohIQVIMTDh2tKLa021yCFMUfiYZvZYylwEMS8EE04xwDD7t7cFJlTTDwKaYSm_qH51kjemhaJrEsaQ3jGiWi6-ojZFwdbE_81JGCcGAZuBdPQvDq199mM1QZA_zWYggpreeU9tkHeimYVnoHMk261W9rdEyFlTYYmOaM0S_i2vrmwJVtZZ4zF1_CHqroRSc4gDwDvxbQYzB_OqD7PUsF8bmrD2tzbdjsTtwazmYGlMnexJjWnUN9EkHualyB4aO8-rS2mPFWHXDDFuwFUHAF5LdEN0rYSPu1FvjrUjnZ-0RU80fsZyx2bzHTWI290auAkWpFQxPKtJQzvMAARM3ueSpBc5hzEvPIGI6mTjNtnIZFk3UxszoJdtun5fb7WA0ZzMxHn97_3z6KGAPpg8XdS2anTVEKVGgyMa67-ynefR-zbjL3QTsHjaM8qPcoVwpdJvZCdj9gZyVdXl8JiXZ9B5znka2aC10HdVS3uZM7Cu-JFjFF2b7WW0TS98Dw-Gnzn8SGieU7A1QkqxBs4waFSYSe3ldizKj0mBhX_UNAk2ses0LUAVnerDzShxiDNUbjfb62rNHxm4zAyDZYeUc7iDdZ3NjS24Q8kSoAkc2LDnRmopuvYfDJCsIIrFd7wEGmCc4g8yy8ENzrKo2Rl1TmmsKhnZrgj2pDKtxd425QHievOva36CzP43pP1VyM0ZJ-EU1nO6cJNQjoalbR8WGdQZ2TdTV3_21BbHDwUliG2OHtVp4unfeKBmPzBXX0iwunDb29R0e2vrpXO5NESvibhMboBkVFAV3luiRdMexg8KuJoPNPiYOPN0Nyf9U_Pllm8YFjpb5pTHxP6tpKvmlwvWn2o8fIyvMoGvXntfRuzMetMcmi_PuwbZ7yRx6Mw8le_FLmtzUPXKSm7B_1JiJa941d0W638_L2Z-lXp5_99f59ySIKxIueTWPpotxHKp10zjm39cFLOfzafBN8HARQLtZDCz1cTDBz2NDfxRM8TPpODhQA_w3nImhOmMfP7r1Xw)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to G B

```ruby
->a,b{a.flat_map{[_1]*b.shift}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhb7de0SdZKqE_XSchJL4nMTC6qj4w1jtZL0ijMy00pqayGqbroWKKRFRxvqGOkYx-ooQBmxXGBRMx0DIDQDiZvqGAKhAUzG0MBAB4hBMgYgUYhhCxZAaAA)

Comment: In both cases, you can avoid the zip, iterate on a only and use `b.shift` for repeating

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes `R` as the first input.
A byte or 2 could be saved if output could be a 2D-array but I'm guessing a flat array is one of the points of the challenge.

```
cÈÇYgV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Y8jHWWdW&input=WzUsMSwxLDBdCls2LDAsMCw2XQotUQ)

```
cÈÇYgV     :Implicit input of arrays U=R & V=A
c          :Flat map U
 È         :Pass each X at index Y through the following function
  Ç        :  Map the range [0,X)
   YgV     :    Index into V
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 72 bytes

```
f(A,R)=[A[i<=∑_{n=1}^{[1...R.length]}R[n]][1]fori=[0...R.total][2...]]
```

Might post an explanation if I feel like it.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xnfpltkd6z)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fnvee6gmm9)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 4 bytes

```
,/#'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LRV1bn4krT1zBVMARCA2szBQMgNNMEAEY4BM4=)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>59</s> 55 bytes

- -2 bytes thanks to [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt).

```c
f(*a,*b,n){for(;n;)~--*b?printf("%d ",*a):a++-b++-n--;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDLbsMgEDybr1i5agQ2pKSPHErSfojFAduhXSvFUWz30Mj9dXexq/YSaRdmhhnQUqnq6MLbNHmeOZmVMoiLb8/cBCO@lcrK19MZQ@95eltDKjMnnl2eq5I6KGXG6QZDdRzqA@y6vsZ2/f7CGAXYh8PAP1usBbuwhBRACY1ZoCss7IH0ZCPhXsKDJLiVoOfaRrbRhGhZs2T8TZXXUk/kmktHFi/4D4QlQEZ4pAREnYYDjiQ31NoAwg46/Dq0HgLc/cFCW0OWfE8Q89yK@V1/GvqOpwX9BNC47dALE2W@ckVjJazKeaOInQ8Wu00jGdk4/QA)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##bU/LTsMwEDzHX7EEUdnxprg8esAtfEjkg5M04Kg4VZNwoMq3h7WD4FJp156dnbE1VV4drX@f54ZnFrMSvbg03Zlrr8VNWSiT529WSiypfZ6/nM7ODw1P72pIMbNCT/Ot89VxrA@w64fadeuPV8ZIxD6t8/yrc7VgF5YQAw6h1Qu0hYE9EJ9sEB4QHpHgFkHF2oZpowjRsWbJ9Osqr7meSRVLhSk88G/wi4GE8EQOCDzFA@6IbqmVBgc76N33oWvAw/0fpOyaJHJP0ElpRPy3OY1Dz9OC0gPF7cZB6EDzlS1ag7Aq40UWExeL3KRhmNg0/wA)

Comment: @jdt, very nice, although I hate that you used `0[b]` unnecessarily ;-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
z⟨kj₎t⟩ˢc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v@rR/BXZWY@a@koezV95elHy///R0WY6BkBoFqsTbapjCIQGsbH/owA)

*-2 bytes thanks to @DLosc*.

*-1 byte thanks to @Kroppeb*

#### Explanation

Given inputs `[a1, …, an]` and `[r1, …, rn]`:

```
z         Zip: [[a1,r1], ..., [an, rn]]
 ⟨    ⟩ˢ   For each sublist [ai, ri]
  k         Take [ai]
     t      Take ri
   j₎       Juxtapose the list [ai] ri times to itself
       c  Concatenate into one list
```

Comment: @DLosc TIL I implemented this behaviour of `=`

Comment: Found a way to use juxtapose: `z⟨kj₎t⟩ˢc` with only 9 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v@rR/BXZWY@a@koezV95elHy///R0WY6BkBoFqsTbapjCIQGsbH/owA "Brachylog – Try It Online")

Comment: @Kroppeb Very nice, using `k` to get a list and not a simple integer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 23 bytes

```julia
a^b=vcat(fill.(a,b)...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PzEuybYsObFEIy0zJ0dPI1EnSVNPT0/zf7ShjpGOcWwclFaosVMoKMrMK8nJ44o20zEAQjOgpKmOIRAaoEobGhjoADFQ2gBV6v9/AA)

Comment: Julia's `fill` saves a lot of bytes: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/PzEuybYsObFEIy0zJ0dPI1EnSVNPT0/zf7ShjpGOcWwclFaosVMoKMrMK8nJ44o20zEAQjOgpKmOIRAaoEobGhjoADFQ2gBV6v9/AA "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks, Steffan! I replaced the code and changed this to a community wiki.

Comment: Note that you don't need to change to a community wiki because someone golfed your answer. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9692/92689

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
ＩΣＥθＥ§ηκι
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjcNAooy80o0nBOLSzSCS3M1fBMLNAp1FECUY4lnXkpqhUaGjkK2po5CpiYIWC8pTkouhupeHq2kW5ajFLsxOtpQx0jHOFYHSsdC5AE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ        Array of values
  Ｅ         Map over values
      η     Array of counts
     §      Indexed by
       κ    Current index
    Ｅ       Map over implicit range
        ι   Current value
 Σ          Concatenate arrays
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 30 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$r)$r|%{,$a[$i++]*$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/RS8MwEMafm7/iGFEal0CrrG9CpeCDL4rzbYwRY8aUdqlJq0Lbv71e2q6PGx@By3c/7r4rza@27qDzXChjdU/3cA9NX0ori5BKTi2jtr1qOJUb@rlcbm/orus7QtKQBDwN0zDmt/yO8bmAscLai7EJS3iESjy44jEqGtCEn4TtGY6jiOPzcDSB2GPQwiOGlOognt@/tKqgIQGGBGrx6b8SLf2BB9Ad@la7Oq/wd41HUYkQmq5WSjuHbngCWsjM8Ufb6s2IJ2eOIDJTlNh0DIT@RnCefAYlweZlndWuMsWYbQsppgsW63Hjwseatnv7YTDkmZGeeh0oe4kaDhnRSzeRoCMd6f8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 87 bytes

The code defines an anonymous function that returns the expected result.
Nothing special here...

```
fn($A$R){$X=[]each$R as$k=>$v;if$v$X=&array_concat($X&array_fill($A[$k]$v))send$X;}
```

### Usage

Just use it normally...
Example using the 2nd test case.

```
$fn = fn($A$R){$X=[]each$R as$k=>$v;if$v$X=&array_concat($X&array_fill($A[$k]$v))send$X;}

// should output: 6,6,6,6,6,0,0
echo &join(call $fn([6,0,0,6], [5,1,1,0]), ',');
```

Since it is an anonymous function, using `call` is required.

### Ungolfed

This code does exactly the same as the golfed version.

This is pretty close to pseudo-code.

```
Set $fn to an anonymous function($A, $R)
Begin.
    Define the variable $result = [].
    Loop through $R as value $value key $key.
    Begin.
        If $value then.
        Begin.
            Set $result to the result of calling &array_concat(
                $result,
                &array_fill($A[$key], $value)
            ).
        End.
    End.
    
    Return the $result.
End.
```

A little further from pseudo-code...

```
$fn = fn($A, $R) => {
    $result = [];
    foreach $R as $key => $value {
        if $value {
            $result = &array_concat(
                $result,
                &array_fill($A[$key], $value)
            );
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ÅΓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOu5yf//R5vqGAKhQSxXtJmOARCaxQIA)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel (ms365), 60 bytes

```
=IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(A1:C1&"|",A2:C2)),"|",,1),"")
```

[image]

---

Or, if you don't mind whole rows as input arrays, for 56 bytes:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(1:1&"|",2:2)),"|",,1),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [I](https://github.com/mlochbaum/ILanguage), 1 byte

```
\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/z/Xz1NXcFKIea/obWRjrGCggKID2ZzmVkb6BjomIFFTK0NdQx1DLgMDQysgRgsZmBt8B8A)

Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 27.

Comment: Answer must be at least 30 bytes; you entered 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 16 bytes

```
{FA({aRLb}MZab)}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCJZIiwie0ZBKHthUkxifU1aYWIpfSIsIlAoeVsxIDIgM11bMSAyIDNdKVxuUCh5WzYgMCAwIDZdWzUgMSAxIDBdKVxuKHlbMTAwLDEwMF1bMCwwXSkiLCIiLCItcCJd)

```
{FA({aRLb}MZab)}     ; First argument = A = a
                     ; Second argument = B = b
{              }     ; Create a function that...
          MZab       ; maps a and b (as zipped pairs of elements) to...
    {aRLb}           ; a block that repeats the (first argument) by (second argument)...
 FA(          )      ; and flattens the resulting list
                     ; (after which the list is implicitly printed out)
```

Comment: The inner function can be a lambda expression: `_RL B` is the direct translation (`_` is the same as `{a}` and `B` is the same as `{b}`), but you can save a byte if you flip the arguments: `BRL_MZba`. Then you can drop the outer curly braces, making it a full program rather than a function, using the `-x` flag to evaluate the inputs as lists: [DSO](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGQShCUkxfTVpiYSkiLCIiLCIiLCIteHAgWzE7MjszXSBbMTsyOzNdIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
mÅaam*─
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/3cGtiYq7WoykN//9HG@oY6RjHKkBprmgzHQMgNAOKmOoYAqEBUMzQwEAHiIFiQLlYAA)

Or alternatively, with the input-lists swapped:

```
^mæ~Ä_;
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z8u9/CyusMt8db//0cb6hjpGMcqQGmuaFMdQyA0AIqY6RgAoRlQzADMNzQw0AHiWAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
m     # Map over the first (implicit) input-list,
 Å    # using two characters as inner code-block:
  a   #  Wrap it into a list
   a  #  Wrap that into a list
      # (e.g. [6,0,0,6] → [[[6]],[[0]],[[0]],[[6]]])
m*    # Repeat each the second (implicit) input amount of times
      # (e.g. [5,1,1,0] and [[[6]],[[0]],[[0]],[[6]]] →
      #  [[[6,6,6,6,6]],[[0]],[[0]],[[]]])
─     # Flatten it to a single list
      # (e.g. [[[6,6,6,6,6]],[[0]],[[0]],[[]]] → [6,6,6,6,6,0,0])
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Unfortunately, using `m*` on lists `[6,0,0,6]` and `[5,1,1,0]` results in `[30,0,0,0]` and lists `[[6],[0],[0],[6]]` and `[5,1,1,0]` results in `[[30],[0],[0],[0]]` (apparently..). Hence the need for two wraps before we can use `m*`.

```python
^        # Zip the two (implicit) input-lists together
         # (e.g. [5,1,1,0] and [6,0,0,6] → [[6,5],[0,1],[0,1],[6,0]]
 m       # Map over each inner pair,
  æ      # using 4 characters as inner code-block:
   ~     #  Pop and push the contents of the pair separately to the stack
    Ä    #  Pop the top, and loop that many times:
     _   #   Duplicate
      ;  #  After the inner loop, discard the top item
         # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 byte

```
Ṙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOGf///4820THVMYv9H22oY6RjHAsA)

Built-in solution.  Input is arg1=R, arg2=A

---

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
Σz(↑∞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziKo1HbRMfdcz7//9/tKGOkY5x7P9oEx1THbNYAA)

Roll-your-own solution avoiding `Ṙ` built-in.

```
Σz(↑∞
 z     # zip the two inputs together with 
  (    #   combination of functions:
    ∞  #   make an infinite list of copies of arg1
   ↑   #   and then take arg2 elements from it;
Σ      # finally, flatten the output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 1 byte

```
/
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=UmVwIOKGkCAvCgrin6g0LDUsNuKfqSBSZXAg4p+oMSwyLDPin6kKCg==)

Built-in solution.

---

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 3 bytes

```
∾⥊¨
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=UmVwIOKGkCDiiL7ipYrCqAoK4p+oNCw1LDbin6kgUmVwIOKfqDEsMiwz4p+pCgo=)

Roll-your-own solution  avoiding `/` (Replicate) built-in.

```
   ¨    # Each: for each element of R arg
  ⥊     # Reshape: reshape to a list of L arg copies
 ∾      # Join: and join all the lists together
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 51 bytes

```
func[a b][collect[forall a[loop take b[keep a/1]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsMwDEPv/Qr9wZKN9dDP2NX44KQOg4Y6hO77M5dWQhgelrqu46Mr8VSWUX57JkFiylar5oOKdakVQtWs4ZBNkWhTbZBHZNfwD5X8xdWb4KKIJ158nwvNCO6Z6Y3oDjeOIcDDFE7E1LolRcE5Nv4)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 6 bytes

```
{y#'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6quVFavqOXiSovWMFQwUjDWtIbSsSAhMwUDIDQDCpoqGAKhAUTY0MBAAYiBwgYgIQArxQ6u)

I don't know if this is accepted or not. Take input as `(A);(R)`.

Render output with `,x` for array with only one element `x`, and `!0` for array with no element (aka null duplication).

Comment: If we're allowed to switch argument order then can be 4 in [oK](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0dfWT3aVMEQCA2szRQMgNAs9v9/AA) - and I assume something similar is possible with ngn/k?

Comment: You can just swap arguments and do `#'` for two bytes

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 21 bytes

```
#(mapcat repeat %2 %)
```

Yay, short built-in names and neat composition!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoAgEEbhvaf4MYRxmS07SrTQSaEwE7HzT8a3eIvH@bneFkXoiAkJE92@su9oscYR42CsVYpqO0vPBZSgfWCNbYbDso@5gjzCwD8r8gE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4.5 bytes (9 nibbles)

```
+!$_~.,$_
```

Input is arg1=R, arg2=A

[Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) has a 'replicate' function, `^`, but it unfortunately does not work on numeric values (the `^` op exponentiates these instead).
So we need to use a slightly more convoluted map, returning the value of arg2 for each element of 1..arg1, instead.

```
 !$_        # zip together arg1 and arg2
    ~       # using the following function:
     .      # map over each element of
      ,$    # 1..arg1
        _   # returning arg2;
+           # finally, flatten the list of lists.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 56 bytes

```
L=[];for k=1:1:numel(a) L=[L repmat(a(k),1,r(k))]; end;L
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 55 bytes

```lisp
(load library
(q((A R)(foldl concat(map* repeat-val A R
```

The second line is an anonymous function that takes two lists. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBCoMwFET3PcUsf4TCj0X3bjxAb/BrLAS@Jk1DwdOncWGpDLMY3mOyXzf171gKaRAH9Y8kaTPkMNKLaMDd0DOoU0xhnSTTIrFBmuMs@foRRTUKjaD6kmHR4mZOw1x@tAfX9AfvqmHB/4Zl3nsYvNPyBQ)

#### Explanation

Too bad the tinylisp library doesn't have a `flatten` function.

```lisp
(q                       ; Two-element list acting as a function:
 ((A R)                  ;  Take two arguments, A and R
  (foldl concat          ;  Fold on list concatenation:
   (map* repeat-val A R  ;  Map repeat-val over corresponding pairs of elements
                         ;  from A and R
```

---

A non-library version is **67 bytes** for a named recursive function that takes the two lists in the opposite order:

```lisp
(d F(q((R A)(i A(i(h R)(c(h A)(F(c(s(h R)1)(t R))A))(F(t R)(t A)))(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9DsIwDIR3nuLGuy0B0T1LHqBvUOiApYifNkufPjhIiCLLPt93lqvdt2LrszXOyHyRI5JoSDTeMIpXFyfZl/VDolhdlNRpX324ERvLY5pR7LJMy6YDM@jPKyKOOOnP7NKzo4jwzQcEr2F/EX5pDKG31N4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 68 bytes

```
import sugar,sequtils
(x,y)=>concat zip(x,y).map x=>x[0].repeat x[1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wc2JBUX5yQrFGmlWCmCWRoWVQnFqYXRmXkmsjkIlgqOJxFSw5VJQSE3OyFdI03CINtQx0jEGKoaxNJElzXQMgNAMLG2qYwiEBqgKDA0MdIAYrMAAJLm0tCRN1-Kme2ZuQX5RiUJxaXpikQ7Q6tKSzJxirmINjQqdSk1bu-T8vOTEEoWqzAKwgF5uYoFCha1dRbRBrF5RakEqUK4i2hBm3AIoBaUB)

-3 bytes thanks to Michael Chatiskatzi

Comment: You can save [3 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wc2JBUX5yQrFGmlWCmCWRoWVQnFqYXRmXkmsjkIlgqOJxFSw5VJQSE3OyFdI03CINtQx0jEGKoaxNJElzXQMgNAMLG2qYwiEBqgKDA0MdIAYrMAAJLm0tCRN1-Kme2ZuQX5RiUJxaXpikQ7Q6tKSzJxirmINjQqdSk1bu-T8vOTEEoWqzAKwgF5uYoFCha1dRbRBrF5RakEqUK4i2hBm3AIoBaUB) by applying the [syntax tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101184/90812)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
Join@@Table@@@In@##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73ys/M8/BISQxKSfVwcHBM89BWVntf0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDg3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXdbWhjpGOca2OgoIClFmrAxQ10zEAQjOgeLWpjiEQGkDEDQ0MdIAYJG4AEuOq/Q8A)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 15 bytes

```
8B 0A 48 83 C2 04 F3 AB AD 85 C0 79 F3 AB C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVJNb9swDD1Lv4Lz0FVulMBp02CIl1563mWnAU4OqiQnKhzJkOTOgeG/voxKkBSDIILke3ykPmTbTndSnk4iHIDBr4zR2a5xb6KBmoOnfkUO7gO07DlUXvVbSoRSgB6HBSVetxCiC4rWK9I4hQ6JOkTQAgloKHm3AXXIhYUFkeYZ5CXVfdTeQvaawfDhjIKaGRvhwXWRg3QWRc6x@C/yeQlntmd5OVL61VjZdErDjxCVcbP9C6UhimgkzuU7GSGNI0XQMCQBUX3f4rnQYvUVCtUW1jDQYZjzR/7Ep/ORf7ojR2DJC1zLC/TM57iKGzgvCp72GSxuwFjS1PIgjGU5HSipnQd2OYzoooNvEVa3@UJOCXJIKvE6dE2slottiZmaXWIOcSaSwUtI6aSW2AaHL8prkdnCyzk2kwlKEtJ6JNUsuzOQ8U/WWaPtotwLz@439j4lRkrorWBjfwq5N1bjAyi9yhIh9etTPw5HDJWD4UqHu@LxN3Y4rhnrbDA7qxUk9Yfc51U/mWDLEf7sTaOBHeELivSvT0n0psBwxrcj3ki@sajUIzieTn9l3YhdOE0PywUa/Klr5OvmHw)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RSI the address of an array `A` of 32-bit integers with a −1 terminator; in RDX, the address of an array `R` in the same form; and in RDI, an address at which to place the result, in the same form. The starting point is after the first 8 bytes.

In assembly, re-arranged for easier understanding:

```
f:  lodsd           # Load a number from A into EAX, advancing the pointer.
    test eax, eax   # Set flags based on that value.
    jns r           # Proceed to r if it's nonnegative.
    stosd       # When -1 is reached, add it to the result array
    ret         #  and return.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
r:  mov ecx, [rdx]  # Load a number from R into ECX.
    add rdx, 4      # Advance the pointer into R.
    rep stosd       # Add EAX to the result array ECX times, advancing the pointer.
# (This section is actually placed at the start; continue at f.)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 34 bytes

```
[transpose[]|range(last)as$_|.[0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCoAwDATvvqIHDwpRUkU/E4IUEVHEqunRt1tTxCwLw07WM0YKl9vl8DIR34rzVGxOQukkH@6akFl/DFlooGUw5kclzlT0gJpeFXVgNcifsIigTQLTmI4ff4TF7xKr8QU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 48 bytes

```
$[a r][flatten map combine a r'x->repeat x\0x\1]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?3C6pC1)

Answer (score 1):

## [q](https://code.kx.com/home/), 5 bytes

```
where
```

## k, 2 bytes

```
&:
```

Built-in [where](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/where/) and indexing does exactly as specified

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 1 [byte](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
▽
```

[Try it online!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=4pa9WzEgMiAzXSBbMSAyIDNdCuKWvVs1IDEgMSAwXSBbNiAwIDAgNl0K4pa9WzAgMF0gWzEwMCAxMDBd)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 9 bytes

```
~zip{)*}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v64qs6BaU6tW9f//6GhDBSMF41gFKB0LAA)

`~` Eval STDIN, input is a list containing the list of items followed by the list of repetitions.

`zip` Zip the two lists together

`{...}%` Map each to:

- `)` Separate the tail from the rest.
- `*` Repeat the rest {tail} times.

Each item of the resulting list is implicitly printed. Although the list isn't flat, it appears flat when printed.